# MetaMask/Web3js ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH issue

Tags: web3js, truffle, dapps, metamask

I've deployed my contract with a UI to Ropsten via truffle and ran `npm run build` and `npm run dev` to start the server. As soon as I launch localhost (with the account in MetaMask selected) in the browser, I get the following error in the browser console.

```
GET http://localhost:8080/app.js net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH
```

The static content shows up, but my dApp can't show the balance in the account and perform functions.

It's happened in the past, but it would go away after a few refreshes. Now it's happening every time and I can't get my dApp to run as expected. Everything was tested and worked with testrpc. Could this be a chrome extension interfering? I tried commenting out all my HTML code and still
got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the AdBlock chrome extension was the issue. Disabled it on my localhost and stopped getting the `ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH` error.